# AppEngine + Datastore + Objectify: Http Request returns inconsistent responses

Tags: google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am implementing AppEngine server as a backend for my Android application. I use Datastore, I query it via Objectify service and I use Endpoints that I call via URL.

I have an entity User with properties like this:

```
@Id
Long id;

/**
 * Name or nickname of the user
 */
public String name;

@Index
public String email;

@JsonIgnore
List<Key<User>> friends;

public User()
{
    devices = new ArrayList<String>();
    friendsWithKey = new ArrayList<Key<User>>();
}

public static User findRecordById(Long id)
{
   return ofy().load().type(User.class).id(id).now();
}


   @ApiMethod(name = "friends", httpMethod = "GET", path = "users/{userId}/friends")
public JSONObject getFriends(@Named("userId") String userId)
{
    User user = User.findRecordById(Long.parseLong(userId));

    JSONObject friendsObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject friend;
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    if (user.friendsWithKey != null)
    {
        for (Key<User> id : user.friendsWithKey)
        {
            friend = new JSONObject();
            User user1 = User.findRecordById(id.getId());
            userList.add(user1);
            friend.put("name", user1.name);
            friend.put("email", user1.email);
            friend.put("id", user1.id);user1.lastTimeOnline.getTime());
            jsonArray.add(friend);
        }
        friendsObject.put("friends", jsonArray);
    }
    return friendsObject;
}
```

It sometimes returns only a subset of friends. It is weird and I do not get where I could go wrong. If I get the User object from the DB, it already has a wrong List of Key values. But if I look into the database via console, I can see all of the users that ahve been added as friends.
I reaally need to fix this bug. Please, help.

It is very strange because it only happens once in a while and is non-deterministic in every way.

Comment: Did you configure the Objectify filter?

Comment: What does it mean, how can I do it amd how does it help? Have you ever encountered such an issue before?

Comment: Try deleting all your data in the datastore and re-adding it and see if the issue persists!

Comment: It does, already tried

Comment: How can it even occur, such an issue?

Comment: I'll bet on the ObjectifyFilter being missing. See https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Setup  Also, the most recent version of Objectify will throw an error if you try to skip this step, so please upgrade.

Comment: There are some serious errors or inconsistencies in how you have pasted this code. Number one: your Endpoints Api -annotated class should not be the same class as your objecitify entity -annotated class. This may not cause errors but is just good practice. Number two: the line "friend.put("id", user1.id);user1.lastTimeOnline.getTime());" doesn't even parse to correct syntax. Number three: the "friendsWithKey" variable doesn't even exist, although there is "friends". Please post actual code that describes what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello? Any change to the code? Please post real code or we can't help you.

Comment: Objectify filter helped solve the problem

Comment: I'm glad to hear. Can you please post a self-answer that describes the steps you actually followed, even from a high-level abstract description in common language?